# how to download CSV file from FTP location and update table using stored proceedure

Tags: sql-server, csv, stored-procedures, ftp

I want to download CSV file from FTP location and update that data into tables using stored procedure. I am not sure how to do that or whether stored procedure is right approach. I have gone through many posts but most of the post talk about pushing data to FTP location.

Any help much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For this requirement you may have to write some Shell Script to connect required FTP Server and download to local system and use to sql loader function supported by the respective database.
If you using some programming  language you can write program to download file from ftp location and read CSV file and insert as batch.

Comment: Hi Aravind, my requirement is, we have shared Azure DB, we don't have access to file system. Can we do it with SP?

Comment: Hey sachin if your requirement is to fetch document from the server(File System where your documents stays) we can write shell script for fetching the data and connect to shared azure db from local machine.